# I have problems with insert loop procedure in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I did a mysql procedure that insert in a table a number of rows for each row of other table. Thats the code:

```
PROCEDURE `name` (`var1` SMALLINT(6), `var2` SMALLINT(6))  BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE a SMALLINT(6);
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE fk_id = var2;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur;

read_loop: LOOP
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    FETCH cur INTO a;
    INSERT INTO tableB VALUES(var1, a);
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur;
```

My problem is that the last row is inserted two times. How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: I have no doubt this is a simplified example, but looping through a result set and inserting seems REALLY inefficient. When all of this code could be reduced to a `INSERT INTO tableB SELECT var1, id FROM tableA WHERE fk_id = var2;`

Comment: Thank you. I need that! I didn't know i could do this.